# Laravel AWS EBS Auto Scaling

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Im looking for some advice, this may seem like a silly question but I am having some issues with understanding how AWS EBS autoscaling works and its best practices.

I have a laravel application that is deployed to AWS EBS through bitbucket pipelines. This all works and deploys successfully.

My issue is when the autoscaling triggers it then brings up a new EC2 instance and then load balances the traffic. The problem is that the new EC2 instance in the fleet is a blank AWS Linux2 AMI so just shows the nginx welcome page.

I think the issue is that it's using a blank AMI and not getting my application. I am guessing i could create an image from the EC2 image running my application and then scale with that but i would have to do that every time i do a deployment.

Can you configure the auto scaling group to replicate the running EC2 instance?

Any help or advice as to the best way to accomplish autoscaling with my application would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Its **depend on the AMI selected in Launch Configuration**..

You need to **create AMI of your live EC2 instance after you updated your all required softwares, dbs, configurations and verified(tested) for proper work..**

then add this AMI to Auto scale Launch Configuration..

you dont need to create AMI for each deployment..

Whenever you makes changes On Ec2 server , or updates your app source code, you need to create new AMI and need to specify that AMI in Autoscale launch configuration.

best practice is to config the auto scale with a **user data script**. So when the new AMI boots up during the auto scaling it reads the user data (cloud init/upstart). The user data script can pull the code from the git or what ever source control and run the necessary pre-deployment commands.